# Python : can't understand this syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

So, here's a chunk of code inside a function :

```
        print('Printing current values ...')

        for key, modbusObject in jsonDict.items():
            print("Object {} contains value {} and timestamp {}".format(key, modbusObject.value, modbusObject.timestamp))

        print('Writing data for loop number '+str(i)+' ...')

        # server.send_message_to_all(jsonDict)
        #print('ho ho ho')
        i += 1          

        cmd = raw_input('Change json data (y/n) ? --type \'exit\' to quit-- : ')
```

All of this is nested in a try ... except statement. Whatever I put in place of i += 1 -> for exemple print('ho ho ho') gets rejected as a 'SyntaxError : invalid syntax'.

I have been stuck on this for 2 days and can't figure out what's happening here that trigger this error...

**EDIT :** more code, as requested :

```
def new_client(client, server):

print("New client connected and was given id %d" % client['id'])
server.send_message_to_all('hello foo')

# global jsonDict
# global i

while True:

    print('Currently connected clients : ')

    try:
        for key, modbusObject in jsonDict.items():
            for case in switch(key):
                if case("coil1000"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1001"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1002"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1008"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1009"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1010"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("coil1011"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1000"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 127
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 365
                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1001"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 8350
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 4633

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1002"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 20
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 15

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1003"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 40
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 10

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1025"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 6
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 3

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1034"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 5

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break                                                                                                                                                           
                if case("inh1035"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 162
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 50

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1036"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 40
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 20

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("inh1037"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 50
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 25

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break                                               
                if case("in1000"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 50

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1001"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 100
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1002"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 40
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 37

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1014"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 350
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 221

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1015"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 200
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 16

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1018"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1000
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1246

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break                                                                               
                if case("in1021"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 2000
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1432

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1086"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 0
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 1

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1094"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 1
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 0

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1102"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 3000
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 50

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                    break
                if case("in1104"):
                    if(i % 2 == 0):
                        modbusObject.value = 100
                    else:
                        modbusObject.value = 3

                    modbusObject.timestamp = dumps(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), default=json_serial)
                if case(''):
                    pass

        print('Printing current values ...')

        for key, modbusObject in jsonDict.items():
            print("Object {} contains value {} and timestamp {}".format(key, modbusObject.value, modbusObject.timestamp))

        print('Writing data for loop number '+str(i)+' ...')

        # server.send_message_to_all(jsonDict)
        #print('ho ho ho')
        i += 1          

        cmd = raw_input('Change json data (y/n) ? --type \'exit\' to quit-- : ')

        if cmd != '':       
            if cmd.lower() == 'exit':
                exit()
            elif cmd.lower() == 'y':
                i += 1
            else:
                pass

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        time.sleep(8)
```

NB :

```
print("New client connected and was given id %d" % client['id'])
server.send_message_to_all('hello foo')
```

and the

```
while True:
```

block are correctly indented, it's just a consequence of the copy/paste that they seems not.

The switch ... case substitute I use is from [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/410692/)

Comment: Maybe mixing tabs and spaces causing invisible indentation errors?

Comment: can you post the actual error? There should be more around that error message like e.g. the line number etc.

Comment: Sadly, everything is perfectly in place.

Comment: @hansaplast 

root@mylinkit:~# python python\ tests/websocket/simulateurModbusToWebsocket.py
  File "python tests/websocket/simulateurModbusToWebsocket.py", line 385
    i += 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Also posting more of the code may help, as there's no error here.

Comment: @SirRobin the error lies outside of the code you posted. I made your code work with defining `jsonDict` and `i` [here](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/a3779a26da9d126c3ee912dfd07f6b19) and this had no error

Comment: After fixing your indentation I don't get an error on this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @melpomene ok you're right I've converted indentation into spaces and get no error. Sorry for that ... (feels dumb...) -> also thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed after converting indents into spaces. Thank you all for your help.